# Running a java in Ubuntu from a file located on the desktop

Tags: java, ubuntu

I running a java program in Ubuntu and it work ok  when I type:

```
javac fileName.java 
java Classname
```

but just when is located in "cd", but when I tried to run it from a file located in the desktop

```
cd / desktop / project
```

it find the file project but when I put

```
javac Filename.java
```

it show and error `<File FileName.java is missing>`.

How I can run the program from a different place that 'cd'

Comment: Please post the complete errors you get

Comment: What do you mean **different place that 'cd'**

Comment: You can only ever compile code in a directory that has code.  There's no guarantee that the path you go down has the code in it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `cd ./desktop/project/ javac <filename>.java` and `cd ./desktop/project/ java <filename>`

Comment: ... or `javac ./desktop/project/Filename.java && java Filename`

Comment: Thank You It work, just a Have to add a space befora and after the /

Comment: Thank You. It worked , I just   added a space before and after the /.          cd./ desktop / project / javac <fileName>.java    and the second row just  java <fileName>

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the full path of "project" directory by opening it in File Manager. Once its opened press *ctrl + l*  and it will highlight the address bar with the full directory path.

Just copy this path and go to this directory from command line.

After this you can run

```
javac Filename.java
```